# Excel file to java objects using a list of lists

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I currently have an excel spreadsheet that I need to change into a java object. 
I have looked into using poiji but it doesn't seem like it's flexible enough to work with my excel model.

[image]

I am using a list of lists:

```
List<List<Attribute<List<SubAttribute<List<Descriptor>>>>>>
```

whereby the description constructor consists of: descriptiontext, details and reply.

The SubAttribute constructor consists of: subattributename and then can contain multiple descriptions.

The Attribute constructor is just the attribute name and then the subattributes

Is this the correct structure to use?

Thanks.

EDIT: Classes

My Class for the Attribute is:

```
public class Attribute<s> {
private final String attName;
private final SubAttribute subAtt;
private final int weight;

public Attribute(String attName, SubAttribute subAtt, int weight) {
        this.attName = attName;
        this.subAtt = subAtt;
        this.weight = weight;
}
```

}

My class for the SubAttribute is:

```
private Descriptor desc;
private String subAtt;

public SubAttribute (String subAtt, Descriptor desc) {
    this.subAtt = subAtt;
    this.desc = desc;
}
```

My class for the Description is:

```
public class Descriptor {
private String Word;
private String Details;
private String Reply;


public Descriptor(String Word, String Details, String Reply, int Mark) {
    this.Word = Word;
    this.Details = Details;
    this.Reply = Reply;
}
```

}

Comment: I would create some classes to make it easier to grasp.

Comment: I've added my code for the classes, thanks for the advice.

Comment: The nested List of Lists thingy is hard to follow.  Can you use composition? For example: `List<Attributes> attributes` has a `weight` field and a `List<SubAttribute> subAttributes`, and `SubAttribute` has a `name` and a `List<Descriptor> descriptions`, and `Descriptor` has Strings `description`, `details`, and `reply`.

Comment: Your classes only support a single `SubAttribute` per `Attribute`, and a single `Descriptor` per `SubAttribute`.